# Was Natsu trying to imitate someone?

Tags: fairy-tail

Fairy Tail and Yankee-kun to Megane-chan have a cross over titled Fairy Megane, and there's one scene when Natsu wore a glasses from Adachi.

[image]

Was he trying to imitate someone? If he did, who was that?

Comment: He was probably trying to parody a Yakuza or a gang member. I've read both series and don't remember coming across such a character.

Comment: i have edited the question a bit, hopefully this helps now

Answer (score 3):

the bit where Natsu says are you here to get burned wearing the glasses is just imitating a yakuza or a gangster because he is wearing the sunglasses and the glasses symbolizes yakuza or gangsters in a way. if you search up yazuka or gangster in google images, you will find that out of the ones that wear sunglasses, they mostly wear glasses that is the same or similar (big lenses) to the glasses Natsu is wearing in the image.
for example
[image]
or here, an anime one
[image]

**EDIT:**
because the other manga was flunk punk rumble, the whole fairy tail guild (in that manga were being punks and acting tough. and yakuza was one of the typical tough guys in that sense.
please excuse my poor English but yeah, hope this helps.